# How do I populate the seed data of a model that has a (one to many) relationship with itself in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, orm

I have a model called person as below:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I have created a relationship between **person** and **leader** (which is still obtained from the class **person** above) such that **person** can have one **leader**, but **leader** can have so many **people** as seen below:

```
class Person < Application Record
has_many :people, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'leader_id'

belongs_to :leader, class_name: 'Person', optional: true
end
```

I have successfully populated the **person** seed file like so

```
20.times do
    Person.create!(first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
                   last_name: Faker::Name.last_name,
                   email: Faker::Internet.email,
                   password: 'password')
  end
```

However, I cannot figure out how to implement the relationship between **leader** and **person** in the seed data file. I am relatively new, can someone please help? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Why model name is plural (people)?

Comment: Having an association with the same name as the table name can make things very interesting.

Comment: I mean `INNER JOIN "people" "people_people" ON "people_people"."leader_id" = "people"."id"` is such a wonderfully readable query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a leader first and store it in a `leader` variable, and then in the loop assign the `leader` variable to all records.

```
leader = People.create!(
  first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
  last_name:  Faker::Name.last_name,
  email:      Faker::Internet.email,
  password:   'password'
)

20.times do
  People.create!(
    first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
    last_name:  Faker::Name.last_name,
    email:      Faker::Internet.email,
    password:   'password',
    leader:     leader      # here the above leader is assigned to each person
  )
end
```

Btw. Ruby on Rails' naming conventions are that models are named in singular and their database tables are named in plural. In your case, a `Person` would be defined in a file named `app/models/person.rb` and it would store its data in a table named `people`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It makes so much sense. You are correct about the naming conventions for the model!! Thanks and God bless :)